# Is it neccessary to make assignment operator private while designing Singleton pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I have just Learned about the first Design Pattern in my career :)
and Implemented it both using early and Lazy method. While it is Logical to
make the Copy Constructor Private but i was told that also make assignment operator private. Since only one instance can be created I think it does not
make sense to declare Assignment operator private.

Comment: Since c++11, you can mark them `delete` instead of private without definition.

Comment: copy constructor and assignment have similar semantic, so it is logical to implement them grouped.

Comment: You can still invoke assignment with code like: `auto& instance = Singleton::GetInstance(); instance = instance;` (even if it should not be problematic).

Comment: A better option would be to stay a million killometers away from the singleton anti-pattern IMHO.

Comment: yeah that is what i have been told..it's an Anti Pattern

Answer (score 0):

> Since only one instance can be created I think it does not make sense to declare Assignment operator private.

It does not make sense to declare Assignment operator at all. Anyway you're right. `public` or `private` it does make any difference because it will never be used.

For those reasons the most practical choice is to avoid to *define* it at all, and make sure it cannot be called: *C++11* has introduced [that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) functionality.

So, you can just delete it.

```
Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
```

Comment: It might be called, as in my example in comment. and prior to c++11, declare private without definition is the way instead of `=delete`. And declare it `=delete` is not the same thing than not declare it at all...

Comment: @Jarod42 I didn't mean what you said.
My answer is quite clear: there is no *practical* difference different into declaring it `public` or `private`. For that reason avoid to *define* (more correct) it using `delete`.

Comment: There are differences between public/private as it can be used. And marking it as deleted is not the same than not declare it as it will be auto generated by compiler.

Comment: *"There are differences between public/private as it can be used."* Ofc, Waht I said there is no **practical** (cite myself) difference **in such context**. *"And marking it as deleted is not the same than not declare it as it will be auto generated by compiler."* I never said that. I just said that *the most practical choice is to avoid to define it, using `delete`*.
English is no my first language but I thing my answer was pretty clear.

Comment: IMO, it is not clear. (BTW, your cite your second sentence about the first one). "avoid to define it, using delete". For example is a *"contradiction"* for me. Probably a language issue.

Answer (score -1):

They may have been referring to an assignment operator which performs copying:

```
Singleton& operator=(const Singleton& other);
```

This implies multiple instances of Singleton, since you would need another instance (the 'other') to copy into the Singleton instance, which doesn't make sense. Therefore, you can make it private or mark it as deleted.